# How to grouping each 3 same records based on the where condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to Grouping each 3 records based on `where` condition 
So , I try to following steps..

This is My Table

[image: This is My Table]

This is My Query .

```
 WITH T AS (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sno) Rank, Sno ,id,Dt, val AS val
    FROM p
    )
    SELECT (Rank-1) / 3 GroupID, id,Dt, SUM(val) AS val ,count(Sno) as Record
    FROM T
    GROUP BY  ((Rank-1) / 3),id,Dt
    order By  GroupID
```

Then I have following the Output.

[image]

Then how to Grouping these Records with `Sum(Val)`...

Comment: I don't think you can use your id in the group by clause. You would need the min or max id.

Comment: It not completely clear in your expected result how `id` and `Dt` get decided.

Comment: How do you determine which id to be chosen? Why GroupID 0 with id 1 while GroupID 1 with id 1 too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by Id will not work. You can take the min or max.

Example:

```
 WITH T AS (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sno) Rank, Sno ,id,Dt, val AS val
    FROM p
    )
    SELECT (Rank-1) / 3 GroupID, MAX(id),Dt, SUM(val) AS val ,count(Sno) as Record
    FROM T
    GROUP BY  ((Rank-1) / 3),Dt--Remove id
    order By  GroupID
```

I created an example here:

http://rextester.com/TCJYIQ73230

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how to aggregate the `id` and `Dt` - assuming you just want then `min`

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sno) Rank, Sno ,id,Dt, val AS val
FROM p
)
SELECT (Rank-1) / 3 GroupID, MIN(id) as id, MIN(Dt) as Dt, SUM(val) AS val ,count(Sno) as Record
FROM T
GROUP BY  ((Rank-1) / 3)
```

Comment: I have different `id`  not  same `id`

Comment: @GBALAG I know, thats why you need to aggregate them using min or max

Comment: I have more then 1000 records with 500 different  type of `id`.

Comment: @GBALAG right. So how do you want to deal with the id? You have to choose something!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as by `cumulative sum`, if i understand correctly :

```
select GroupID, dt, sum(val) as val, count(*) as record
from (select *, 
            sum(case when id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by sno)-1 as GroupID
      from p
     ) p
group by GroupID, dt;
```

Honestly, i have a no idea about `id` as appears in o/p.